# Chose Type to populate from JSON data based on contents of that data

Tags: c#, json.net

Here's the data I'm trying to deserialize

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "Conference Room 3D",
            "code": "room1",
            "type": 0,
            "bounds": {
                "southWestLat": 42.06258564597228,
                "southWestLng": -88.05174744187781,
                "northEastLat": 42.062638767104781,
                "northEastLng": -88.05170306794393
            }
        },
        // ....
    ]
}
```

This is quite simple when I'm only expecting a certain kind of data, however I need to be able to put other types of data in that elements array. The type pair is an enumeration which specifies that type of data the object holds. That number then maps to the Class which the object should serialize to.

For Example

- 0 maps to MapElementConferenceRoom
- 1 maps to MapElementFocusRoom
- etc.

I thought I could just write a custom JsonConverter to read the type key, however you cannot rewind the JsonReader object.

Any suggestion for a solution would be greatly appreicated

Comment: Not sure the exact way of doing it, but I do know JSON.NET supports .NET's dynamic object.  That should be able to allow to investigate the type pair and update the data accordingly.

Comment: I'll investigate that, thank you.

Comment: `elements` is an array. Do you want to deserialize every item ot if to a different type of object depending on `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynJson.elements)
{
    if(item.type==0)
    {
        //Do your specific deserialization here using "item.ToString()"
        //For ex,
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MapElementConferenceRoom>(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a view model that maps directly to the content. then project the specific implementations based on the view model.

Comment: Sorry but, what's a view model?

Comment: just that. a model of the data from the view (request). in this case it is an intermediate object between the serialized data in the request and the data model you need to process the request.